# Django User Is Logged Out outside the home page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a django website. Now the problem is, after I sign in as a User or an Agent, the correct links only show up on my home page. Whenever I visit another page, the correct links are gone and are replaced with 'Sign In' and 'Agent Sign In'. Somehow the user is logged out outside of the home page. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

My models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='CustomUser_set', blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.')
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='customuser_set', blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.')
    is_user = True

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'



class Agent(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    agent_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    bio = models.TextField()
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='agent_set', blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.')
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='agent_set', blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.')
    
    is_agent = True
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'agent_email'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('agent-dashboard', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Agents'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Agent {self.name}'
```

My forms.py:

```
User = get_user_model() 

class UserSignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not isinstance(user, User):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "This form is for User login only")
        return super().confirm_login_allowed(user)

class AgentSignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not isinstance(user, Agent):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "This form is for Agent login only")
        return super().confirm_login_allowed(user)
```

My backends.py:

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        return None

class AgentAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            agent = Agent.objects.get(Q(username=username) | Q(agent_email=username)) 
        except Agent.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        
        if agent.check_password(password):
            return agent
        return None
```

My middleware.py:

```
class AgentAuthenticationMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if hasattr(request, 'user') and request.user.is_authenticated and isinstance(request.user, Agent):
            request.user = request.user
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

My signals.py:

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(user, Agent):
        request.user = user
```

My AgentLoginView and UserLoginView:

```
class UserLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_backend = "users.backends.UserAuthBackend"
    template_name = 'users/login.html'
    form_class = UserSignInForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("Before login, request.user:", self.request.user)
        
        agent = form.get_user()
        # Set the authentication backend before login
        agent.backend = self.authentication_backend
        login(self.request, agent)
        self.request.session['is_agent'] = True
        self.request.session['user_type'] = 'user'
        self.request.session['is_authenticated'] = self.request.user.is_authenticated
        print("After login, request.user:", self.request.user)

        return redirect('home')

class AgentLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_backend = "users.backends.AgentAuthBackend"
    template_name = 'users/agent_login.html'
    form_class = AgentSignInForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("Before login, request.user:", self.request.user)
        
        agent = form.get_user()
        # Set the authentication backend before login
        agent.backend = self.authentication_backend
        login(self.request, agent)
        self.request.session['is_agent'] = True
        self.request.session['user_type'] = 'agent'
        self.request.session['user_slug'] = agent.slug
        self.request.session['is_authenticated'] = self.request.user.is_authenticated
        print("After login, request.user:", self.request.user)

        return redirect('home')
```

My home view:

```
def home(request):
    agents = Agent.objects.all()
    properties = Property.objects.all()

    # Check if the user is authenticated and retrieve user information
    is_agent = request.session.get('user_type') == 'agent'
    user_slug = request.session.get('user_slug')

    # Retrieve the full user object using the stored information
    user = Agent.objects.get(slug=user_slug) if is_agent and user_slug else None
    
    is_authenticated = request.session.get('is_authenticated')
    # Print debugging statements
    print(f"User: {user}")
    print(f"Is Agent: {is_agent}")

    context = {'agents': agents, 'properties': properties, 'is_agent': is_agent, 'user': user, 'is_authenticated': is_authenticated}
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```

My base.html:

```
{% if is_authenticated %}
  {% if is_agent %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'agent-dashboard' user.slug %}">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'agent-sign-out' %}">Agent Sign Out</a></li>
  {% else %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Sign Out</a></li>
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'agent-sign-in' %}">Agent Sign In</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of another view?  It looks like you're only setting is_authenticated / is_agent for the home view (for lack of other evidence) which would be your problem

Comment: Yes other views don't have the is_authenticated / is_agent context

Comment: What if you add the request to the template context and then replace `{% if is_authenticated %}` with `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`. Do you still see the buttons for unauthenticated users?

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform when I replace it with `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`, it only works for Users then. I don't see the unauthenticated links. But when I login as an Agent, I don't even see the authenticated links for Agents on the home page then, nvm other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, that's because the `is_agent` and `is_authenticated` variables are only present being set by the `home` view. Since you're setting session variables at login, you can use them in the templates:

**base.html**

```
{% if request.session.is_authenticated %}
  {% if request.session.user_type == "agent" %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'agent-dashboard' user.slug %}">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'agent-sign-out' %}">Agent Sign Out</a></li>
  {% else %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Sign Out</a></li>
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'agent-sign-in' %}">Agent Sign In</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

**HOWEVER**, this is a hack implementation. You have two user objects and I hope you can see you're doing a lot of [unnecessary] work. This becomes hard to maintain.

Instead of multiple user objects, just have one custom `User` model with `is_agent` attribute. Then your other types of users can have their own models with a `OneToOne` relationship to your user.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_agent = False

class Agent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,..., related_name="agent")
    ... 
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.user.is_agent = True
        self.user.save(update_fields=["is_agent"]) 

class Regular(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,..., related_name="regular")
    ...
```

That way, you are only authenticating one user object. Then you only need one login form, one login view, no custom auth backend.

And for the links in the base template:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  {% if request.user.is_agent %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'agent-dashboard' user.slug %}">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'agent-sign-out' %}">Agent Sign Out</a></li>
  {% else %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Sign Out</a></li>
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  {% if request.user.is_agent %} 
  <li><a href="{% url 'agent-sign-in' %}">Agent Sign In</a></li>
  {% else %} 
  <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a></li>
  {% endif %} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried the `one custom User model with is_agent attribute.` The problem there is, when agents register from the agent register page, they have to select a user, otherwise the error pops up `NOT NULL constraint failed: users_agent.user_id`. So I think I am gonna stick with the hack implementation.

Comment: Hack Implementation also has a problem, i.e. whenever I go to `Agent Dashboard` link after logging in as an Agent, I get the error `Reverse for 'agent-dashboard' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['agent\\-dashboard/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']`. Why would is happen?

Comment: Your second error is because you're passing `user.slug` in the `agent-dashboard`, but `user` is undefined. You can replace it with `request.user.slug` but I am unsure which user it will be, the `agent` or `custom_user`, since you defined `slug` on Agent model only.

Comment: For first error, you can easily assign `user` when an `agent` registers. Besides, I don't see a good reason of letting them choose a user when signing up.

Comment: For the second error, yes the error persists after changing it to `request.user.slug` because `slug` is only defined in agent model, not in user model. So what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Then use the `user_slug` from your session: request.session.user_slug. Again, this is a lot of work, man.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. I know this is not the best way to do this, but thank you so much for showing me the way.